# Creating a Property Inspection Score Checklist

Tags: java, calculation

Each question should be answered with a score ranging from 0 to 3.0 along side it with a weighted value, after every answer is scored it should calculate and output
total average score using Java.

Below is portion of the code done but am face with

> Error:(41, 13) java: illegal start of expression

```
class entry {
        private String description;
        private double weight;
        private double score;

        public entry (String description,double weight, double score) {
            this.description = description;
            this.weight = weight;
            this.score = score;

        }
        public double getFinalScore() {
            return score * weight;

            public static void main ( String[] args) {
    entry en1 = new entry ("Free from debris/rubbish/or other items such as suitcases and laundry (score low for high amount of debris)",0.15d, 3.0d);
    entry en2 = new entry ("Reception exists, if no reception a viable alternative entry area in a building or approaching a unit", 0.09d, 2.5d);
    entry en3 = new entry ("Lighting sufficient ",0.09d, 1.2d);
    entry en4 = new entry ("Free from odor", 0.15d, 0.24d);
    entry en5 = new entry ("Overall welcoming feel", 0.24d, 2.6d);
```

Comment: This is not a free coding service. What have you tried so far and where exactly did you get stuck ?

Comment: I just need a couple lines of code to run the calculations and inputs so I can then rinse and repeat and start building the code from there

Comment: again this is not how SO works. Unless you post/demostrate some effort/code and ask a specific code question on where exactly you are stuck, your question will be closed / put on hold.

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback, Ill edit the post and demonstarte what I have tried so far.

Comment: I'm afraid your (non-existent) question is still way unclear. I highly doubt that anyone could understand what exactly your problem is (since you don't ask any specific question), or have any clear idea on how your current code relates to what you posted in the image. I'd suggest you first check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then try to improve your question a bit

Comment: So I've added the code I've been working on. The odds and evens now that am thinking about it shouldn't be there I think. In therms of what am looking for to get calculating a score total, is this going in the right direction?

Comment: see the answer I posted. It proposes a simple way on how you could achieve what you want in an object oriented manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, I don't think your current code is anywhere close to what you want to do. Please see below some minimal example of how this could look like.

First you can create a class that would represent each field/area of the property, eg :

```
public class Field {
    private String description;
    private double weight;  
    private double score;
     
    public Field(String description, double weight, double score) {
        this.description = description;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.score = score;
    }
    public double getFinalScore() {
        return score * weight;
    }
    // other getter/setters as needed
}
```

Then in a main class,I create 3 `Field` instances (for demo purposes) with the relevant description string, the weight, and a sample score (eg up to 3.0) for each one, then print out the total score :

```
public static void main( String[] args)  { 
     Field f1 = new Field("Free from debris..." , 0.15d, 2.0d);
     Field f2 = new Field("Level of street noise..." , 0.09d, 3.0d);
     Field f3 = new Field("Overall safe..", 0.24d, 1.0d);  

     System.out.println("Total score for all fields : ");
     System.out.println(f1.getFinalScore() + f2.getFinalScore() + f3.getFinalScore());
}
```

The above code prints out :

> Total score for all fields :
>
> 0.81

Comment: This helped so much, so appreciate this! Ive gone ahead on and completed the code but i get "Error:(41, 13) java: illegal start of expression"

Comment: @Mark cannot tell what's wrong as I can't see your code obviously. Such error usually means syntax errors. So check your syntax, opening/closing braces etc

Comment: Oh I've just but my code up now in my initial post, its worth noting that I have repeated the code and edited accordingly to the amount of questions in my original excel (48 questions)

Comment: There's a missing closing brace in your getFinalScore() method...

Comment: Ah I see, and what about  "public static void main ( String[] args) {" am getting things like "token is missing", I've added that line of code 5 times over when going in description and getting an error for each except the very 1st one

Comment: You should really go and read some tutorials on **java basics**. Especially on how a class is structured. The errors you get indicate syntax / structure errors and again from the code you posted it's not clear what's wrong, apart from the things I already told you (curly braces)

Comment: Yeah I had a look into what makes a main class before but I shall continue to study it and get a better understanding. My full code has at the end closing braces so that's not an error. Iv'e tried looking it up but can I continue to create a main class in the same coding window/tab or do I have to open a new class? Thanks again for all your help!